# AIR for iOS StageVideo Volume Control

Tags: ios, video, air, volume

I'm loading and running an MP4 just fine in AIR for iOS on iPad 2.

The problem I am having is controlling the volume (muting / unmuting).

I am using soundTransform on the NetStream object, but it is having no effect.. it's not erroring either.

```
var transform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
                transform.volume = 0;
                netStream.soundTransform = transform;
```

Is this even possible on iOS (iPad)? or are just supposed to use the physical volume control?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it would appear that this is not possible:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#soundTransform

> Note: This property is not supported for H.264 video in AIR 3.0 for
>   iOS.

Shame...